# No internet after 16.04 LTS 18.04.01 upgrade

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, ethernet

This may seem like a duplicate, but many solutions have been unsuccessfully tried. Currently I have no internet, WIFI or Ethernet. Sometimes: "no wifi adapter found".  The device is HP dm4, dual boot with Windows 7.

Here is the [wireless script output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/q6HKVYzHY4/) The issue started 3 weeks ago as no GUI after 16.04 LTS to 18.04.01 upgrade.  At that time, I was able to use the terminal to connect to the Internet and run "fixes" in [Upgrade to 18.04.01 from 16.04 LTS... Login but no Gnome Gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065485/upgrade-to-18-04-01-from-16-04-lts-login-but-no-gnome-gui)  Then mysteriously, the GUI ran after restarting several times.  But since then, I am unable to connect to the Internet in the terminal or GUI.

There is a chatroom [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82382/discussion-on-question-by-c-martin-upgrade-issues-18-04-01-from-16-04-lts-unm) about my issues.

```
sudo nmcli c up <saved WIFI connection>
```

only appears to connect.

```
sudo nmcli d wifi list
```

shows strong signal strength, but ping to google and nyt fails.

The phone I use as a hotspot shows a successful connection.

In the GUI **Network Tools** show the phone/hotspot recently used minutes ago, the **Available Networks** list shows the phone/hotspot as available with a check mark, but the "connect" button is grayed out and unfunctional.

`REGDOMAIN=00` and attempts to change this has failed as others describe. I have a similar set up to the one described by cipricus in [Wifi regression on 16.04 Centrino Wireless-N 1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770681/wifi-regression-on-16-04-centrino-wireless-n-1000)
and the situation described in [this deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041654/how-to-initialize-centrino-wireless-n-1000-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04)

Comment: May we meet in your chat?

Comment: @chili555 Please!!! yes I will meet you in chat!  how do I connect with you there?

Comment: You are in there now, just respond to my hail.

Comment: I'm on an iPhone and I might not be seeing your hail... Looking...

Comment: Here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82382/discussion-on-question-by-c-martin-upgrade-issues-18-04-01-from-16-04-lts-unm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During our long chat, we determined that you *were* connected to the internet; we showed it with:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
```

...which succeeded. However, pings to www.ubuntu.com did not succeed. This pointed to a problem with DNS nameserver resolution. We ran:

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

Your result was:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 1 22:07 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

In your case, resolv.conf was not pointing to systemd as expected. Therefore, we removed and recreated the link:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Upon reboot, the computer connected and was able to ping names and numbers with no difficulty.

I also recommended a full update and upgrade; about 1700 packages were upgraded.

I'm glad it's now working as expected.

Comment: After many reboots this fix continues to work.  Dr. Chili is officially knighted in my book for endless patience with a particularly ornery newbie ( me ) and valor saving the world from an invisible, shape-shifting dragon ( the code misalignment ).   This fix took 3 days and countless hours chatting over a dial-up connection.  Many thanks to the forces that be which created Dr. Chili!  

Comment: *blush* Thank you for your kind words. I'm glad it's working as expected.

Comment: This is simple and effective diagnosis and answer. I had the same issues. So other folks know, the result of doing `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` after the fix is now: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep 23 12:49 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`