# Connected but no internet on Asus ROG, "operation not permitted" for ping

Tags: networking

I have a dual boot ASUS ROG laptop with Ubuntu and Windows. Few days ago internet stopped working on Ubuntu - I am connected to the network, but with no internet, in Windows everything works perfectly.

[image: Output of some commands that may help]

Output of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

I tried [No internet after 16.04 LTS 18.04.01 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071252/no-internet-after-16-04-lts-18-04-01-upgrade) and now I am able to ping ip addresses, but I can't ping using names. After trying using web browser ping starts to say:

```
send msg: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100652/discussion-on-question-by-wojciech-malecha-connected-but-no-internet-on-asus-rog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! (Probably not the best one)

First I discovered why my /etc/resolv.conf was being overwritten all time: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot
So:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and answered no to dynamic updates. Now I rebooted and then I added "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base, run `sudo resolvconf -u` and removed iptables package. Rebooted again and it worked!