# Internet access possible only through Tor browser after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, browser, tor

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. Since then, I am able to access Internet only through Tor browser. Before the upgrade, I could access Internet using a normal Chrome/Firefox browser without involving Tor. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing proxy setting in the browser chrome & firefox? Try "No proxy" or "Bypass" (Default is: System wide settings)

Comment: Yes. I did that but still cannot access without Tor.

Comment: did you check firewall settings? Probably `http` / `https` are blocked (80 and 443)

Comment: Have you tried other OS on the same network? Maybe your phone or something else? Maybe something else changed?

Comment: @Mateusz Konieczny : Other OS (Windows) on the same network is working fine. Nothing else is changed. ISP is the same, so are the WiFi settings.

Comment: This sounds like a DNS issue. Please run `nmcli device show | grep -E "IP4.DNS|IP4.GATEWAY|IP4.ADDRESS"` and check if something is not right. Also to rule out this point or to fix it if you spot something is wrong, try refreshing your lease by running `sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient` two or three times and check your DNS again using the first command above then try internet and see if this helps. Best Of Luck

Comment: <br>
try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071252/no-internet-after-16-04-lts-18-04-01-upgrade). <br>
Looks quite similar.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg-query -l dnscrypt-proxy` ? Please [edit] that into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add Google servers? That's a hard reset I do sometimes after updating NordVPN I cannot access the internet neither Chromium or Firefox but Telegram works perfectly fine, like what a hack... There's a *hard reset* I use by overwriting `resolv.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

delete what is inside and add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save it and close. `Resolv.conf` gets overwritten all the time by your system environment so you won't do much damage to the network it more likely will produce *debug* effect.

Now run

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Or click switch *On / Off* network icon.

You can find lots of variants in [this old thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) as well as similar to my way of workaround above and use it as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an incorrectly configured Internet connection, so you are experiencing problems with the Internet.

Tor when installed downloads a number of packages torsocks lynx and may be some others installed by you that affect the quality of the connection.

To resolve the situation, you need to do the following.

> 1. Make sure that the output of ifconfig or ip addr shows the correct settings.
> 2. Remove all packages related to the Internet.
> 3. Make sure that the contents of /etc/resolv.conf correct 4. Check how the Internet is configured on the system, and if you use a network Manager or any other connection Manager, try to remove them and configure a static connection.
> 4. Reinstall browser
> 5. Check your gateway or router
> 6. Reboot pc.

Also, here duplicate question?
[No internet after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04)